# How can I modify service linked role's `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS` policy in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am deploying a Rancher service which users the service linked role `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS` to provision resources in AWS.

During deployment I got below error:

```
The provided role doesn't have the Amazon EKS Managed Policies associated with it. Please ensure the following policies [arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy] are attached
```

it says the service role doesn't have EKS managed policy assoicated with it. Both the role `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS` and its policy `AmazonEKSServiceRolePolicy` are managed by AWS. I tried to update them but failed because they are not allowed to modify. And I also can't create another service role for EKS.

I got below error when trying to create another service role for EKS:

```
$ aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name eks.amazonaws.com --custom-suffix Rancher

An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the CreateServiceLinkedRole operation: Custom suffix is not allowed for eks.amazonaws.com
```

Is there anyway for me to modify the role to attach other policies?

Below is the full policy for the role: `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "eks-cluster-sg*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "kubernetes.io/cluster/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "kubernetes.io/cluster/*"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Name": "eks-cluster-sg*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/eks/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/eks/*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/eks/*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If the service linked role is not in use, you can [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html#delete-service-linked-role) it and [recreate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html#create-service-linked-role) it using the cli, as the error said for this types of role you can't add a prefix

Comment: I tried to delete it but failed. How can I find who is using this role?